# Create json objects from logs with ELK Stack

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch, logging, logstash

I have some logs generated by the bridge between Quality Center (HP Alm) & Jenkins: Something like this:

```
    Building in workspace D:\Tools\Jenkins\workspace\*******-JenkinsWithQC
[Dani-JenkinsWithQC] $ D:\Tools\Jenkins\workspace\*******-JenkinsWithQC\HpToolsLauncher.exe -paramfile props20022014150821066.txt
"Started..."
Timeout is set to: 5
Run mode is set to: RUN_REMOTE
============================================================================
Starting test set execution
Test set name: JenkinsIntegartionTest, Test set id: 2457
"Number of tests in set: "2
Test 1: [1]Login will run on host: si0vm839
Test 2: [1]Logout will run on host: si0vm839
"Scheduler started at:20.02.2014 15:08:28
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
20.02.2014 15:08:29 Running: [1]Login
20.02.2014 15:08:29 Running test: [1]Login, Test id: 938, Test instance id: 1412
Test: [1]Login, Id: 1412, Execution status: Running
Test: [1]Login, Id: 1412, Execution status: Error, Message: Access is denied
20.02.2014 15:08:33 Test complete: [1]Login
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
20.02.2014 15:08:33 Running: [1]Logout
20.02.2014 15:08:33 Running test: [1]Logout, Test id: 939, Test instance id: 1413
Test: [1]Logout, Id: 1413, Execution status: Running
Test: [1]Logout, Id: 1413, Execution status: Error, Message: Access is denied
==============\nJob timed out!\n==============
================================================
Run status: Job failed, total tests: 2, succeeded: 0, failures: 0, errors: 2
Build step 'Execute HP tests from HP ALM' changed build result to FAILURE
Finished: FAILURE
```

I want to create a JSON from these logs that looks like something like this:

```
{
    'Build': {
         'TestSet': [
             {
                  'name' .   : 'execution',
                  'id'       : 2457,
                  'startedAt': '20.02.2014 15:08:28',
                  'nbOfTests': 2,
                  'tests' .  : [
                      {
                           'name': "[1]Login",
                           'host': "si0vm839"
                      }
                  ]

             } 
         ]
    }
}
```

I can do this with a python script that handle line by line with regex and create the JSON, but I think it's not optimized as I'm new to Python...

**I want to know if i can do this with Logstash to store them in Elasticsearch and build a kanban dashboard.**

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do it with Logstash, involving the multiline codec on ingestion and some truly *gnarly* grok statements. That's not a project I would look forward to. In fact, I'd tackle it one of two ways:

#### Use the `ruby` filter

This allows inline ruby to massage that massive string into the fields you want on the event. Effectively, you're writing your own `codec` this way.

#### Use the `exec` input

This offloads the process of transforming it into a parseable format to an external script, which then emits it to logstash for injection into ElasticSearch. Since I don't think you're running multiple of these a second, this may work for you.

Comment: thanks for your reply, can you explain a little bit more.. i'm new to ELK stack... thanks again

Comment: @steep2000 The ruby and exec filters are both expert-mode features of Logstash, since they handle the `other` cases the existing filters don't. A primer on getting either working well and integrated would be a 30 minute conference talk by itself. With the `exec` plugin, you can call the python script you already built. It will need tweaking for input/outformat, but that's your fastest way to working.